# HTML Imports Cross Browser Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, html-imports

For the past few days I've been looking at HTML Imports for example:

```
<link rel="import" href="imports/header.html">

var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
var header = link.import.querySelector('.header');
var panelPrimary = link.import.querySelector('.panel-primary');
var panelInfo = link.import.querySelector('.panel-info');
var panelWarning = link.import.querySelector('.panel-warning');
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.appendChild(header.cloneNode(true));
container.appendChild(panelPrimary.cloneNode(true));
container.appendChild(panelWarning.cloneNode(true));
container.appendChild(panelInfo.cloneNode(true));
```

I know it works in the latest versions of chrome.
I really like the idea and I'd like to know if there's a way to make it cross browser and would it be good enough for commercial project?

If not, are there any good alternatives similar to this?

It looks like when loading a `<template>` file held in an external html file you can really get working on the page lightning fast so I'm interested in looking into this.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=html+imports+polyfil

Comment: http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/html-imports/

Comment: I've downloaded an run those demos but for some reason I just get blank pages. Can they not be run straight from the folder on my desktop computer?

Comment: I'm testing it on firefox 43.0

Comment: `I've downloaded an run those demos` ... which demos are you talking about?

Comment: The ones here: google.com/search?q=html+imports+polyfil

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible using polyfill [`Webcomponents.js`](http://webcomponents.org/) (or its *lite* version, or `HTMLImports.js` directly)

You'd better follow the second link (posted by @Derek).

If you need a tutorial on HTML Imports, read [this one](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/?redirect_from_locale=fr).

If it still doesn't work, post your code.